# PHP myadmin 404 when opening table

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I don't know why this happened but for some reason when I open PHP myadmin in brower it will load fine. When I try to open a table I get a 404 error. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

I am using XAMPP on Windows 7 for future reference.

I have looked everywhere to no prevail.

Here are some screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIO9k.jpg

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to post images.

Comment: does mysql in ACTIVE status in the XAMPP Control Panel ?

Comment: Yes everything works fine, I can post to the Database and everything. I just am unable to actually look at the table in PHP myadmin

Comment: can you show me a screenshot ?

Comment: Can you try downloading a fresh install of phpmyadmin and overwriting the current module?

Comment: Alright, I will try that

Comment: have you activated  Virtual hosts?

Comment: I am going to reinstall, yes I activated my Virtual Hosts. My website had worked and everything for a while. This just randomly happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everybody I kind of forgot about this. The reinstall did fix the problem. Thanks so much for your help.